# Are red obstacle lights near an airport required to be lit during the day?

Tags: faa-regulations, safety, visibility

What are the FAA Beacon Light Requirements for 80 foot tall High Mast Poles Near an Airport?  Specifically, do the RED beacon lights need to be illuminated 24 hours per day?  Or, do they only  need to be illuminated at night?

Here are examples of Holophane high mast pole installations around the country.

https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.236398096375560.78767.131284353553602&type=3

https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.194847107197326.56223.131284353553602&type=3

Answer (score 4):

It's unclear exactly which lights you're referring to (none of the example pictures you linked to are red), but the [FAA AC on obstruction lighting](http://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgAdvisoryCircular.nsf/0/b993dcdfc37fcdc486257251005c4e21/$FILE/AC70_7460_1K.pdf) says that only structures over 200ft are required to be lighted:

> Any temporary or permanent structure, including all  appurtenances,
>   that exceeds an overall height of 200  feet (61m) above ground level
>   (AGL) or exceeds any  obstruction standard contained in 14 CFR part
>   77,  should normally be marked and/or lighted.

However, there are exceptions:

> The FAA may also recommend marking and/or  lighting a structure that
>   does not exceed 200 (61m)  feet AGL or 14 CFR part 77 standards
>   because of its  particular location.

The same document describes the use of red lights:

> **Aviation Red Obstruction Lights**. Use flashing beacons and/or steady
>   burning lights during  nighttime

The rest of the document suggests that red lights are for night use and white for day use. The FAA also has a dedicated [portal](https://oeaaa.faa.gov/oeaaa/external/portal.jsp) for obstruction evaluation and reporting if you're involved in building or managing potential obstacles.