# What lights are used on top of a building or structure near an airport?

Tags: safety, airport, airport-lighting

What type of light (strobe, beacon, color) should be displayed on top of a building or structure near an airport ?

Comment: For what country?

Comment: See also (for the US): [Are red obstacle lights near an airport required to be lit during the day?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/8528/3201)

Comment: Country this question relates to is the Philippines.

Comment: I should also add that the building is only 23 m above ground. Located about 2km from the airport but not in it's flight path.

Answer (score 6):

The general guidelines are:

> 4.3 Lighting Systems. Obstruction lighting may be displayed on structures as follows:
>
> 1. Aviation Red Obstruction Lights. Use flashing lights and/or steady-burning lights during nighttime. Tower structures are typically
>      marked with flashing red lights. Buildings and smaller obstructions
>      located near airports should be marked with steady-burning red lights.
>      (See Chapter 5).
> 2. Medium-Intensity Flashing White Obstruction Lights. Medium-intensity flashing white obstruction lights may be used during
>      daytime and twilight with automatically selected reduced intensity for
>      nighttime operation. When this system is used on structures 700 feet
>      (213 m) AGL or less, other methods of marking and lighting the
>      structure may be omitted. Aviation orange and white paint is always
>      required for daytime marking on structures exceeding 700 feet (213 m)
>      AGL. This system is not normally recommended on structures 200 feet
>      (61 m) AGL or less.
> 3. High-Intensity Flashing White Obstruction Lights. High-intensity flashing white obstruction lights may be used during daytime with
>      automatically selected reduced intensities for twilight and nighttime
>      operations. When this system is used, other methods of marking and
>      lighting the structure may be omitted. This system should not be used
>      on structures 700 feet (213 m) AGL or less, unless an FAA aeronautical
>      study shows otherwise.
>      Note: All flashing lights on a structure
>      should flash simultaneously except for catenary support structures,
>      which have a distinct flashing sequence between the levels of lights
>      (see paragraph 4.4).
> 4. Dual Lighting. This system consists of red lights for nighttime and high- or medium-intensity flashing white obstruction lights for
>      daytime and twilight. When a dual lighting system incorporates
>      medium-intensity flashing white lights on structures 700 feet (213 m)
>      AGL or less or high-intensity flashing white lights on structures
>      greater than 700 feet (213 m) AGL, other methods of marking the
>      structure may be omitted.

Specific details are spelled out in [AC 70/7460-1L CHG1](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC_70_7460-1L_Change_1_Obstruction_Marking_and_Lighting_10062016.pdf) Obstruction Marking and Lighting.